# Return ResponseEntity vs returning POJO

Tags: rest, spring-boot

My application is based on Spring Boot with some REST endpoints. Is there any difference between below return statements?

- `return new ResponseEntity<MyBean>(myBean, HttpStatus.OK)`
- `return myBean;`

Is there any best practice guidelines or any technical difference?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`ResponseEntity<T>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) represents the **entire HTTP response**. Besides the *body*, its API allows you to set *headers* and a *status code* to the response.

Returning just a bean is fine but doesn't give you much flexibility: In the future, if you need to add a header to the response or modify the status code, for example, you need to change the method return type.

For more details on return values, refer to the Spring MVC [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types).

Answer (score 10):

Returning the `ResponseEntity` gives you more control over how the HTTP Response is generated, especially when it comes to HTTP status codes and other headers.

You could easily create a response with `HttpStatus.CREATED` or an specific error code to tailor your API.

If you are OK with a HTTP 200 and a serialized version of your POJO, simply returning the POJO is fine.

If you want more control when designing your API, use ResponseEntity.