# SprintBoot REST API to return XML as response

Tags: spring-boot

I am learning SpringBoot and have this piece of code that is able to understand incoming JSON responses and return a JSON response to the client ( POSTMAN ). I am trying to get a feel of SpringBoot and wanted to configure it to return an XML response instead.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces =  {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> addMovies(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        service.addToMovies(movie);

        // Return a ResponseEntity instead.
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

If I set Accept HTTP header with value application/xml, I am getting this error:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class io.fireacademy.restapi.restapiaws.models.Movie] with preset Content-Type 'null']
```

Not sure why this error is coming up. Also, why does it say, Resolved?.
I have looked at existing threads over this and see that my pom.xml already has the entries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

My SpringBoot controller class code:

```
package io.fireacademy.restapi.restapiaws.controllers;

import io.fireacademy.restapi.restapiaws.models.Movie;
import io.fireacademy.restapi.restapiaws.services.MovieRecommendationService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/movies")
public class RestAPIController {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRecommendationService service;

    // When to return a ResponseEntity
    // Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49673660/return-responseentity-vs-returning-pojo

    @GetMapping
    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return service.getMovies();
    }

    // Learning: The annotation @PathVariable is needed to inject the value in the URL onto the variable.
    @GetMapping(path="/{movieId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> getMovieById(@PathVariable String movieId) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(service.getMovie(Integer.parseInt(movieId)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // TODO: Why is a List<Movie> failing in POST API and not in GET API
    // TODO: What is the use of produces/consumes
    // Learning: The client need to set Content-Type HTTP header set so that the server can understand how to process the body data.
    @PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces =  {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> addMovies(@RequestBody Movie movie) {
        service.addToMovies(movie);

        // Return a ResponseEntity instead.
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(movie, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping(path="/{movieId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> updateMovies(@PathVariable String movieId, @RequestBody Movie movie) {

        // Return a ResponseEntity instead.
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(service.updateAMovie(Integer.parseInt(movieId), movie), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping(path="/{movieId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Movie> deleteMovies(@PathVariable String movieId) {

        // Return a ResponseEntity instead.
        return new ResponseEntity<Movie>(service.removeAMovie(Integer.parseInt(movieId)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    // TODO: Integrate this onto a Javascript code
}
```

I also updated the consumer too. Same result though.

```
@PostMapping(consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }, produces =  {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE })
```

Please give me any clues.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Using Jackson**
   Spring MVC uses the Jackson library by default for JSON responses. When we add the Jackson Extension jackson-dataformat-xml to the classpath, Spring MVC will automatically pick this up and use for XML responses.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

2. **Using JAXB** 
   If the Jackson XML extension is not available in the classpath Spring MVC will use JAXB for the transformation. However, to make this working, we must annotate our response object with the @XmlRootElement annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class CommentDTO {
    private String id;
}
```

**Returning JSON and XML** 
Sometimes we want to support JSON and XML responses on the same endpoint and method implementations. For that, we only need to add a second MediaType to the produces parameter like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE  })
public CommentDTO getComment(@PathVariable(value = "id") String commentId) throws IOException {
    return service.get(commentId);
}
```

Now the client must send in the Accept header the content type it wants to receive.

```
Accept: application/xml
```

If the client does not send a Accept header, Spring MVC will fall back to the configured default content type. You can change it like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
  }
}
```